# Customized Raven revision document id

Tags: ravendb

I've used `_docStore.Conventions.IdentityPartsSeparator = "-";` for the normal document ids, for using it in mvc but when I use revision document Ids. I get the id with "/". Is there a way to customize the revision ids too?

Answer (score 1):

No, because the conventions are only *client side conventions*.  The RavenDB server has no way to know that you have changed your conventions.  The versioning bundle operates from a server-side trigger.

Comment: So??? Is there any other cure or solution to make use of the Revision document Id?

Comment: I am assuming you are talking about the versioning bundle?  How it has its ids as `products/1/revisions/1`.  When you change your convention, you are using keys like `products-1` and getting revision keys of `products-1/revisions/1`.  No - you can't do anything about that.  And it shouldn't really matter.  If I misunderstood, or this is causing some actual problem, then please edit your question and elaborate.  Thanks.